# Recurrence Relations for the harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

For the hermite polyniomials the Rodrigues formula states:
$$
H_n(\xi) = (-1)^{n}e^{\xi^2}\left(\frac{d}{d\xi} \right)^n e^{-\xi^2}
$$
If we differentiate this expression we should obtain:
$$
\frac{dH_n}{d\xi} = 2nH_{n-1}
$$
However, I am a bit confused why the result is $2nH_{n-1}$, this was my reasoning:

$$
\frac{dH_n}{d\xi} = (-1)^{n} \frac{d}{d\xi}\left(  e^{\xi^2}\left(\frac{d}{d\xi} \right)^n e^{-\xi^2} \right)
= \frac{1}{(-1)}(-1)^{n+1}e^{\xi^2}\left(\frac{d}{d\xi} \right)^{n+1} e^{-\xi^2} = -H_{n+1}
$$
I am not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: Did you differentiate the $e^{\pm \xi^2}$'s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you didn't apply the product rule for derivation correctly. You have, directly:
$$\frac{dH_n}{d\xi}=(-1)^n\left[ 2\xi e^{\xi^2}\left( \frac{d}{d\xi}\right)^ne^{-\xi^2}+e^{\xi^2}\left( \frac{d}{d\xi}\right)^{n+1}e^{-\xi^2}\right]$$
Instead of having the $(n+1)$-th derivative, we can derivate inside and have
$$\frac{dH_n}{d\xi}=(-1)^n\left[ 2\xi e^{\xi^2}\left( \frac{d}{d\xi}\right)^ne^{-\xi^2}+e^{\xi^2}\left( \frac{d}{d\xi}\right)^{n}(-2\xi e^{-\xi^2})\right]$$
The rest is applying Leibniz's product rule for $n$-th derivative to the second term
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(fg)=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\frac{df^k}{dx^k}\frac{dg^{n-k}}{dx^{n-k}}$$
Also, you will need to notice that for $k\geq2$ the corresponding $f=-2\xi$ vanishes, so you only have to calculate for $k=0$ and $k=1$. You should be able to do that now.

Comment: I erroneously subtracted $+2\xi e^{\xi^2}...$with $-2\xi e^{\xi^2}...$, that was my mistake. Its all clear now

Comment: These things happen. Glad it's clear now.